# Формирование объекта циклом

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ie11

Уже который час сижу и в голову не приходит как осуществить реализацию объекта такого типа.
имея лишь только массив r_arr c объектами, которые выгружаются с базы данных access.
Объектов в return может быть не 3, а бесконечно.(столько сколько одинаковых дат в массиве), так же и в  plannedReferences: в каждой дате,тоже может быть бесконечное количество объектов.
Помогите получить этот return пожалуйста.

```js
r_arr =[
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-18',workShiftStringName: 'Late shift', referenceID:24, plannedQty: 5},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-18',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift', referenceID:25, plannedQty: 7},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift', referenceID:27, plannedQty: 9},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift', referenceID:28, plannedQty: 11},
];
 
//что тут надо сделать?
  
 return[{
                workShiftDate: '2020-12-18',
                workShiftStringName: 'Late shift',
                plannedReferences: [
                    {
                        referenceID: 24,
                        plannedQty: 5
                    }]
            },{
                workShiftDate: '2020-12-18',
                workShiftStringName: 'Day shift',
                plannedReferences: [
                    {
                        referenceID: 25,
                        plannedQty: 7
                    }]
            },{
                workShiftDate: '2020-12-19',
                workShiftStringName: 'Day shift',
                plannedReferences: [
                    {
                        referenceID: 27,
                        plannedQty: 4
                    },{
                        referenceID: 28,
                        plannedQty: 11
                    }]
            }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ещё вариант, совместимый с IE 9

```js
let r_arr =[
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-18', referenceID:24, plannedQty: 5},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-18', referenceID:25, plannedQty: 7},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19', referenceID:27, plannedQty: 9},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19', referenceID:28, plannedQty: 11},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19', referenceID:22, plannedQty: 13},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-20', referenceID:33, plannedQty: 4},
];

const result = r_arr.reduce(function(acc, value) {
  // Group initialization
  if (acc.every(function(item){return item.workShiftDate != value.workShiftDate})) {
    acc.push({workShiftDate: value.workShiftDate, plannedReferences: []});    
  }
 
  // Grouping
  acc.filter(function(item) { return item.workShiftDate == value.workShiftDate})[0].plannedReferences.push({
  referenceID:value.referenceID, plannedQty: value.referenceID});
 
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Updated.

тут прос100

```js
r_arr =[
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-18',workShiftStringName: 'Late shift', referenceID:24, plannedQty: 5},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-18',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift', referenceID:25, plannedQty: 7},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift', referenceID:27, plannedQty: 9},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift', referenceID:28, plannedQty: 11},
];

const result = r_arr.reduce(function(acc, value) {
  // Group initialization
  if (acc.every(function(item){return item.workShiftDate != value.workShiftDate || item.workShiftStringName != value.workShiftStringName})) {
    acc.push({workShiftDate: value.workShiftDate, workShiftStringName: value.workShiftStringName, plannedReferences: []});    
  }
 
  // Grouping
  acc.filter(function(item) { return item.workShiftDate == value.workShiftDate && item.workShiftStringName == value.workShiftStringName})[0].plannedReferences.push({
  referenceID:value.referenceID, plannedQty: value.referenceID});
 
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо!огромное!!))

Comment: Наверное я буду вашим должником) как сделать так чтобы фильтр применялся и по workShiftStringName: 'Late shift' или  'day shift'. то есть на выходе если сейчас 2 одинаковые даты он  помещает referenceID и plannedQty в plannedReferences. А что есть у меня есть  workShiftStringName:'Day' или 'Late'. И необходимо сделать так чтобы если один из workShiftStringName в двух одинаковых датах разный то разделить эти даты.

Comment: Я поправил пример. МЫ с вами сочтёмся за помощь)

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин да конечно, разберёмся чуток попозже. Мне чуток поработать надо :)

Comment: Да не проблема подправить под ваш код единственно нужно поменять условия группировки и всё

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин Обновил ответ добавил ваш случай

Comment: Я правильно помимаю что мне фильтр теперь применить не по дате а по смене?

Comment: Ай молодец какой)) радости нет предела, сам так делал, только не получалось из за того что вместо && ставил || в групировке.

Comment: как с тобой связаться чтобы отблагодарить)) что то не нашёл тут личных сообщений

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117372/discussion-between---and-aziz-umarov).

Answer (score 3):

Вот так, как вариант

```js
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
    value: function(predicate) {
     // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If IsCallable(predicate) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
      if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }

      // 4. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
      var thisArg = arguments[1];

      // 5. Let k be 0.
      var k = 0;

      // 6. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
        // b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
        // c. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, T, « kValue, k, O »)).
        // d. If testResult is true, return kValue.
        var kValue = o[k];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
          return kValue;
        }
        // e. Increase k by 1.
        k++;
      }

      // 7. Return undefined.
      return undefined;
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  });
}


let r_arr =[
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-18', referenceID:24, plannedQty: 5},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-18', referenceID:25, plannedQty: 7},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19', referenceID:27, plannedQty: 9},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19', referenceID:28, plannedQty: 11},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19', referenceID:22, plannedQty: 13},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-20', referenceID:33, plannedQty: 4},
];

const result = r_arr.reduce(function(acc, value) {
  // Group initialization
  if (!acc.find(function(item){return item.workShiftDate == value.workShiftDate})) {
    acc.push({workShiftDate: value.workShiftDate, plannedReferences: []});    
  }
 
  // Grouping
  acc.find(function(item) { return item.workShiftDate == value.workShiftDate}).plannedReferences.push({
  referenceID:value.referenceID, plannedQty: value.referenceID});
 
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: забыл уточнить что у меня IE11, на нем код в консоли жалуется на синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: Поставьте логирование для определения места?

Comment: Я с телефона через часок доберусь до компа

Comment: вместо (acc, value) => переделал на function(acc, value) вместо item=> item.workShiftDate == value.workShiftDate сделал function(item){return item.workShiftDate == value.workShiftDate} и уперся в ошибку что объект не поддерживает метод find

Comment: Если заработало то могу поменять

Comment: было бы здорово если бы вы помогли дожать до конца)

Comment: а так работает?

Comment: это как раз про то что и говорил, нужно еще перед if Тоже самое проделать с заменой и тогда какраз выходит на ошибку по поводу метода find

Comment: я подобным образом переделал второе предложение от @DiD, но ругается на синтаксис перед ...new Set, удалил эти 3 точки(не знаю для чего они, если знаете был бы благодарен) и стало кое как но отображать обьекты, но не так как в примере

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: спасибо, поизучаю) но опять же это не для IE ахах

Comment: может добьем до рабочего состояния ;)?

Comment: Добавил полифил find https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Спасибо, за отзывчивость) попробую через часик.

Comment: Если не получается то перепишу через every и filter

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин три точки заменяются `Array.from()`

Comment: @DiD спасибо за информацию!!!)))

Answer (score 2):

```js
const r_arr =[
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-18', referenceID:24, plannedQty: 5},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-18', referenceID:25, plannedQty: 7},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19', referenceID:27, plannedQty: 9},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19', referenceID:28, plannedQty: 11},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-19', referenceID:22, plannedQty: 13},
{workShiftDate:'2020-12-20', referenceID:33, plannedQty: 4},
];

console.log([...new Set(r_arr.map(v=>v.workShiftDate))].map(d=>({workShiftDate:d,plannedReferences:r_arr.filter(r=>r.workShiftDate == d).map(r=>({referenceID:r.referenceID,plannedQty:r.plannedQty}))})));
```

Comment: ваш вариант тоже не работает в IE11 =(

Comment: поправил немного код, и уперся в ...new Set, может можно его заменить?

Comment: var result =[...new Set(r_arr.map(function(v){return v.workShiftDate}))].map(function(d){return ({workShiftDate:d,plannedReferences:r_arr.filter(function(r){return r.workShiftDate == d}).map(function(r){return({referenceID:r.referenceID,plannedQty:r.plannedQty})})})})
console.log(result)

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин зачем заменять `new Set`?

Comment: Зачем IE11? Почему не IE6? В нём даже `microsoft.com` не работает! https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-365-apps-say-farewell-to-internet-explorer-11-and/ba-p/1591666

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой и рабочий вариант для IE.

```
const array = [
  {workShiftDate:'2020-12-18',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift 1', referenceID:24, plannedQty: 5},
  {workShiftDate:'2020-12-18',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift 2', referenceID:25, plannedQty: 7},
  {workShiftDate:'2020-12-19',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift 1', referenceID:27, plannedQty: 9},
  {workShiftDate:'2020-12-19',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift 2' , referenceID:28, plannedQty: 11},
  {workShiftDate:'2020-12-19',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift 1', referenceID:22, plannedQty: 13},
  {workShiftDate:'2020-12-20',workShiftStringName: 'Day shift 2', referenceID:33, plannedQty: 4},
];

function groupByDate(array) {
  const pre = {};

  array.forEach(function (el) {
    const key = el.workShiftDate + '@' + el.workShiftStringName;
    if (!pre[key]) {
      pre[key] = [];
    }

    pre[key].push({
      referenceID: el.referenceID,
      plannedQty: el.plannedQty,
    });
  });

  return Object.keys(pre).map(function (k) {
    const keys = k.split('@');

    return {
      workShiftDate: keys[0],
      workShiftStringName: keys[1],
      plannedReferences: pre[k],
    };
  });
}

console.log(groupByDate(array));
```